# Does Big O notation also represent space complexity?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, space-complexity

Big O notation represents how long a method takes to run as input gets larger.

**Does it (the formula) also represent space complexity?**

Comment: You can _use_ Big-O notation to describe the space complexity of an algorithm/function, but note that the space complexity is an entirely different entity than the time complexity, so these will describe two _separate_ cases, even for the analysis of the same algorithm. Have a look at time & space complexity for e.g. different sorting algorithms (quick googling; e.g. [here](http://bigocheatsheet.com)). Some can be preferred is execution time is of essencem whereas space is not, and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Big-O notation is used to represent Space Complexity. Big-O notation in Space complexity is similar to that of Time complexity. It represents the "maximum amount of space used by the algorithm at anytime".